# Is it possible to extend the global search in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

We want to extend the global search in SharePoint Online with a custom search extension that also searches content not directly available in SharePoint.

Is this generally possible?

Answer (score 1):

You have essentially two options for "extensions" to create a search experience in SharePoint Online. Which you choose depends on how you want the results to be delivered to the user.

You can develop client side code that makes a request from your external system and integrate that into the search experience. The downside is that the results are not commingled or relevance ranked in SharePoint. This is more of a "federated" option. You would have to deploy the same code on-prem to keep the experiences in sync.

The other option is to use Hybrid Search. Crawl the external content from a SharePoint 2013/2016 farm hosted on-prem and send the indexable content to Office 365 to be included in the index. Now, when you query SharePoint online from any SharePoint site (on-prem or Online) you will get the search results from all systems in the same result set. They will be commingled and relevance ranked. They will also show up in Delve (if you want).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have any links to deep dive into both topics? I got the general picture from your answer, but we need more information on how the solutions can be achieved and what their up-/downsides are.

Comment: The first solution is pure development. It all depends on your target system. The second is augmenting the crawler. So it too depends on what you want to crawl. If it is a database, web server or other content source SharePoint supports natively, just crawl it. If it's not you need to develop or purchase a BCS connector. Then configure hybrid search.